# Can someone explain what did Feynman wanted to explain in his lectures (Vol 1, Chapter 4.2.)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

This is the text from [Feynman lectures - Vol. 1 - Chapter 4-2 Gravitational potential energy](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html#Ch4-S2):

> Consider weight-lifting machines—machines which have the property that they lift one weight by lowering another. Let us also make a hypothesis: that there is no such thing as perpetual motion with these weight-lifting machines. (In fact, that there is no perpetual motion at all is a general statement of the law of conservation of energy.) We must be careful to define perpetual motion. First, let us do it for weight-lifting machines. If, when we have lifted and lowered a lot of weights and restored the machine to the original condition, we find that the net result is to have lifted a weight, then we have a perpetual motion machine because we can use that lifted weight to run something else. That is, provided the machine which lifted the weight is brought back to its exact original condition, and furthermore that it is completely self-contained—that it has not received the energy to lift that weight from some external source—like Bruce’s blocks.

What is the meaning and analogy in this text? Which law or principle does Feynman want to explain? How is energy going through this process of weight-lifting?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Comment: [Feynman Chapter 4](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html)

Comment: This section of the Feynman Lectures seems to get lots of questions. Try looking through the links in the Related column on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys

Answer (score 0):

What Feynman wants to say is that the total energy of a closed system should always be conserved.

So if you find that a weight has been lifted but the weight lifting machine is still in its original (initial) configuration, then that should not be possible unless someone from outside the system provided the energy to lift that weight.
This also means that the external agent had to do some work and therefore, supply energy to the system. But the additional energy still came from somewhere in the Universe.

In conclusion, I cannot do some work without removing the same amount of energy from some other region of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

What Feynman does is to consider the weights and the weight lifting machine as the system/

[image]

He then considers the weights as part of the system being lift up and therefore being capable of doing more work than before they were lifted.
He then asks the question. with the weights in the lifted position can the weight lifting machine go back to exactly its configuration before it lifted the weight without any input from anything external to the system.
The answer is "no" unless the weights were moved back to their original position.

Put another way, if the weights are to stay in the lifted position and the weight lifting machine restored to its original condition there must be an input from sources external to the system.

He is giving an example of the ideas behind the law of conservation of energy and later writes,

> In fact, that there is no perpetual motion at all is a general
> statement of the law of conservation of energy.

That is not the end of the story in that one con conceive of perpetual motion machines which do not violate the law of conservation of energy but [none the less do not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Classification).